# VIM: execute autocommand on enew

Tags: vim

I want to automatically set the `paste` mode on when I open a new file (an empty file that doesn't exist).

```
autocmd BufNewFile * :set paste
```

in the vimrc does the trick with `vim newfile` or `:e newfile`, but not with `:enew`.

How can I run an autocommand on `:enew`?

Comment: You could try with `BufCreate` instead of `BufNewfile` it should be triggered each time you load a file which isn't listed.

Comment: just to ask. Is "paste" mode useful? I always using + (plus) register, wich refers to system clipboard.

Comment: @statox: Thanks but unfortunately `BufCreate` will also set paste mode when I open existing files.

Comment: @dartNNN: `"*p` does seem to do the trick. It doesn't really solve the issue of executing an autocommand on `:enew`, but it does help with my specific use-case, thanks.

Comment: @emmanuel I didn't get exactly what you wanted, indeed `BufCreated` isn't a good solution then.

Answer (score 2):

`set paste` will have many side effects, e.g. disable indention. I would imagine the requested behavior would become annoying quickly.

Alternatives:

- Use `'pastetoggle'` setting to setup a key to toggle `'paste'`,
- [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired)'s `yo` mappings which put Vim in insert mode with `'paste'` set and disables `'paste'` upon leaving insert mode
- [vim-bracketed-paste](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste) enables transparent pasting into Vim for certain terminals.

For more help see:

```
:h 'paste'
:h 'pastetoggle'
```

Comment: I'm happy to toggle `paste` off once I'm done pasting (or on the rare occasions where I do write a file from scratch), but I'd still like it to be the default for empty buffers, as I rarely ever write a file entirely from scratch, and more often than not open a new buffer just to do some quick editing on something in my clipboard. I'll look into these plugins though, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, the following will run an autocommand on `:enew`:

```
autocmd BufCreate * if '' == expand("<afile>") | set paste | endif
```

You can replace `BufCreate` with `BufAdd` or `BufNew`, it will work all the same. The important part is the `if '' == expand("<afile>")` that will only execute the command if it the new buffer has no name.

**NB:**

For the specific use-case of pasting text in new buffer, auto-switching to `paste` mode is not a great solution though, I wouldn't recommend using this.

As the `paste` is maintained even when you switch buffer. You'd need additional autocommands to unset the `paste` mode when you switch buffer/window (`autocmd WinEnter * set nopaste` will work for windows, but for some reason `autocmd BufEnter * set nopaste` doesn't help when switching buffer).

To ease pasting stuff in new buffers (or otherwise), I'd recommend either:

- typing `"*p` or `"+p` in normal mode, as to use vim's native mechanism to paste from the clipboard registers, as suggested by @dartNNN (assuming you're on your local machine)
- using one of the plugins recommended in @peter-rincker's answer